# Change redirect url after product save

Tags: magento-1.9, product, adminhtml, products-management

I am working on multi website for a single admin.

I need to change the `store` URL parameter after saving a product. In which function does the redirection after saving a product happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/contollers/Catalog/ProductController.php
```

on line 714 this function

```
public function saveAction()
    {

}
```

you can check the redirection in end of function

Comment: When i use this file in local folder but it is not work for me, it takes only core file.

Comment: you cannot copy the controller into local and edit because controller need to override the controller.

Comment: How can i do this.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/ follow this link

Comment: In provided example "Frontend" folder is used so it is correct to use because i think here i am working for admin section.

Comment: no it is not big issue you can create your own folder system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30579/discussion-between-mathew-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: follow my code paste my code and check. i tried that code and it's working